# Ngrx subscription not called across lazy boundries

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

In my app.component [AppModule], in ngOnInit() I create a subscription to a property in my state called lastRouterUrl.  The way it works is that I have a reducer that handles the ROUTER_NAVIGATION action and updates this field when creating the new state.

Any navigation within the AppModule results in the reducer being called and the lastRouterUrl in the state updated followed by the above subscription being called.

However, I also have some lazily loaded feature modules, when those are navigated to and when the user navigates in routes internal to the lazy module the following occurs.  The ROUTER_NAVIGATION action fires, the reducer runs and returns a new state, the store is updated (as I can see in DevTools) however the subscription created in the root module is never called.

Also, if I move the above subscription to the lazy module itself everything works fine!

It seems like any dispatches and subscribers between lazy/eager module boundaries are mutually exclusive, i.e. a dispatch that occurs and results in a change of state does not notify a subscriber listening for that change if that subscriber is in another module.

How is is possible to remedy this?  This actually does not seem right to me.  If I subscribe to a change of a property in the store my subscription should be called regardless of whether the source of the change was in the same module or a different module and whether that different module was lazy or not.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, figured this out.. I had a duplicate import in my feature module that was creating a new store.  Caught this in the dev tools in the store instances dropdown and noticed there were 2 instances.  So the original subscription was against the 1st store and the ROUTER_NAVIGATION action was in the same reducer but updating the 2nd store.